Discrepancy between Stitch (GA4 API) extracted data and Ga4 UI Data
We are extracting ga4 data via the given api through stitch into our data warehouse.
However when we aggregate the metric "total_users", we found 12% discrepancy between data that is shown in the ga4 UI interface and that is available in the table in the data warehouse via stitch platform.
I was told by the developer from stitch that Google uses a different logic for data aggregation hence wanted to understand what can be the issue here and what measures one can take to resolve this?
What logic does google use to aggregate data?
Any suggestions or ideas that any of you may have would be much appreciated.
Requesting help.
Thank You.
I saw one comment here in stack overflow that deactivating google signal will solve the problem due to the data threshold.
However I have tested this on our dev GA4 property ID in which the google signal is turned off, I can still see the data discrepancy between GA4 Api data and GA4 UI data.
